# Does JOIN in a database lead to code duplication in the application?

Tags: sql, join, web-applications, architecture

For example, we have a web application that uses PostgreSQL. The application has AuthorService that implements CRUD operations for Author entity. AuthorService uses "authors" table in database.

Now we need to implement BookService, which should fetch data from "books" table. BookService must join the Author entity.

If we use SQL JOIN in the BookService, then we need to repeat some logic (code) from the AuthorService in the BookService, since the AuthorService contains the access control logic for the Author entity and logic for generating the URLs of the author's photos (S3 signed URL)

OR we can use the AuthorService inside the BookService to fetch the data and after we can join this data in the application instead of PostgreSQL (we can write a loop that join entities), but in this case we may have performance problems.

Which option is better?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are not using an ORM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).  Instead of repeating code from the AuthorService within the BookService, I would look at extracting the common functionality into a third service.  Also, use a join to multiple database calls - otherwise performance will suffer.  It sounds like your service layer is doing quite a lot of interaction with the database - while I don't have much context on your system, I would differentiate between repository classes (to interact with the DB) and the service layer (where actual logic resides).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the right place to do the JOIN is in the database, even if it might mean some extra code needed from the application side as you have said so.

Joining inside the application layer would blank out any database optimizations which the database optimizer is capable of making use had "join" been inside the db. The database the optimizer chooses the option to return back records on the basis of statistics on the tables/columns/histograms values and a whole lot of optimizations .

Take for example a looping logic. If we have a small table called dept and a large table called emp and if we are to perform a query join on the two in the db. It is most likely going to use a nested loop which might be more efficient since the large table needs to be traversed just once to get all matching records.And if the dept table is wide(many columns) the optimizer can choose to use an index and get the same output in an efficent manner

In case both of the tables are large the optimizer may choose a hash join or sorted join.

Consider the alternative, in your application if you were to join, you would be using just the looping logic all the time(mostly a nested loop) or if you are to implement an sophisticated algorithm of doing the "join" you would be duplicating all of the effort which has gone into making the database.

So best option in my humble opinion - Use db for any SET related operations (JOIN,FILTER,AGGREGATION)